# Conditional sentence, If clause for "would go"

Tags: word-choice

I have grammar test with the following question:

```
We are having an exam tomorrow. If we ______ to study, we would go out tonight.

(A) Didn't have
(B) Don't have
(C) Hadn't
(D) Hadn't have
```

That looks like a type II conditional sentence, but I can't extrapolate it's examples to this specific case.

Can you please point out the right choice here, and explain it? (I would like to hear the explanation for incorrect options as well.)

Comment: 98% of native speakers (of American English) will say A. One percent might say C.   That is my argument for both why A is correct in American English, and why the others aren't. Usage determines what is grammatical.

Comment: 'Have to' takes do-support for interrogatives and negations, (B') 'If we don't have to study, we will go out tonight' is correct, but the counterfactual usage is (A) 'If we didn't have to study, we would go out tonight.' // Note that colloquial 'have got to' _doesn't_ take do-support: 'If we hadn't got to study, we would go out tonight.'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Conditional if" deals with three types of sentence as given hereunder: 
1. If you **work** hard, you **will** pass.
(1st part is Present Indefinite Tense and 2nd part is Future Indefinite Tense).
2. If you **worked** hard, you **would** pass.
(1st part is Past Indefinite Tense and in 2nd part we use 'would').
3. If you **had worked** hard, you **would have passed**.
(In 1st part we use 'had with 3rd form of the verb' and in 2nd part 'would have with 3rd form' is used).

In the existing case the second part contains 'would' so the first part will have be in  Past Indefinite Tense. So the sentence becomes: **If we didn't have to study, we would go out tonight.**

Source : ["Conditional If" sentences in English](https://youtu.be/ekPbHtbuTl4). The referred video is yet not in English version but still may prove useful.

Comment: -1 because there are at least 100  more conditional sentences than the three you mention. Search for 'conditional' on this website.

Comment: Follow-up question then: why `didn't have` and not `hadn't have`? They both sound like a Past Indefinite

Comment: @AlexAbdugafarov :  There is 'would go' in the 2nd part, so in the 1st part we need to use 'Past Indefinite Tense. In the Past Indefinite Tense we use 2nd form of verb for affirmative sentences and for negative sentences - we use "didn't with first form". Hadn't is not used in Past Indefinite Tense.

Comment: @Alex: *hadn't have* is wrong no matter what. You need to use a past participle after *hadn't*, so it would be *hadn't had*.

Comment: Had + past participle is always followed by "would have + past participle"

Comment: @RajinderGoswami — except in mixed conditionals: *If you had bought Microsoft stock in 1990, you would be a multimillionaire now.*

Comment: @PeterShor: - No Sir,  had +  past participle is always followed by 'Would have + past participle'.

Comment: No. ESL classes only teach a small fraction of the possible forms of conditional sentences – admittedly, the most common ones. But the ESL rules only work if both clauses are in the same time frame (both past, both present, both future). Here, *had bought* is past, but *would be* is present. See Clare's comment above.

Comment: If you don't believe me, see this [BBC website](http://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/intermediate/unit-24/session-2/activity-2) on mixed conditionals.

Comment: @PeterShor: I saw BBC website just now. The site is declaring that both of us are right.

Comment: According to @tchrist in answer to ELU's [how many conditional sentence types are possible?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316123/how-many-conditional-sentence-types-are-possible) there are at least 277 possible conditional sentences.